# sklearn.impute.MissingIndicator ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').:

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, valueerror, imputation

While creating and testing some examples with sklearn's impute library (v0.0.20) I ran into to the above error. I set up the following simple example and want to create a MissingIndicator feature for the NaN's and 999's.

Everything works fine for the NaN's, but if I try to replace the missing values parameter by 999 I get this error. According to the documentation numbers should be fine.

[image]

Here's the code and the error:

```
X = pd.DataFrame(
    np.array([5,7,8,-5,0,25,999,
              1,-1, np.NaN, 0, np.NaN])\
              .reshape((4,3)))

from sklearn.impute import MissingIndicator
indicator_1 = MissingIndicator(missing_values=np.NaN)
indicator_1.fit_transform(X)
indicator_2 = MissingIndicator(missing_values=999)
indicator_2.fit_transform(X)
```

[image]

I know it's really is easy to build a working missing indicator yourself. But I was wondering if I'm rather using the library wrongly, or if this is some internal problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The parameter `missing_values` is to tell the algorithm to consider the value specified in it as missing value. So when you do `missing_values=999`, this means that the model will treat 999 as the missing values and change that. Not sure what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: As mentioned in my question I want to threat both NaN's and 999 as a missing value indeed. @VivekKumar, if you have tried my code, you should have noticed this throws an error when ' the model will treat 999 as the missing values'. The idea of to missing indicators is to merge them later to one (boolean) missing indicator feature (indicator_1 + indicator_2).

Comment: I tried your code and thats why commented. I was only talking about the design of MissingIndicator in scikit. There is no option to treat different types of values as missing, is it? You only specify a single type using `missing_values` attribute and hence its assumed that only that type of missing info is present. The error is thrown when that assumption does not hold valid for the data

Comment: . If you want to treat both as missing values, then you can (1) convert one to another (`np.nan` to 999) before passing them to MissingIndicator (2) Use two different MissingIndicator instances on different columns and then join them (you can use FeatureUnion for that).

Comment: Thanks for your return. I already used the FeatureUnion to work around the error. The problem seems to be that if you set missing_values to 999 AND there are np.NaN's in the frame, the error will be thrown. If I replace the NaN's by 999 the missing indicator works fine. (I think the question can be closed now).